# What does "Remotable" mean?

Tags: android, api-doc

What do the Android API docs mean when they talk about a "remotable object"?

For example the API docs for [IBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html) state:

> This interface describes the abstract protocol for interacting with a
>   remotable object.

But I've searched and can't seem to find any definition such as "A remotable object is an object that ... blah blah blah..."

Comment: Search for "remote objects" in java and/or android.

Comment: @323go: Ahh so it's another made up word courtesy of the api-doc writers and it should really read "This interface describes the abstract protocol for interacting with a remote object."?

Comment: Your sarcasm is quite misplaced. It's not at all a made-up word, but quite frequently used -- it's an object that can be made remote. Just like "editable" is something that can be edited, and "teachable" is someone who can be taught.

Comment: While I respectfully disagree, I concede this is now in the area of semantics and language and falls outside the purpose of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`IBinder` is an interface that allows IPC (Inter Process Communications) among other things. As you may know, all apps (most of the time) run on their own process and cannot interact with apps running in other processes directly. One method you can use to create an interaction between them is by using a  `IBinder`. `IBinder` allows communication between those "remote" objects.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark this question as answered.

Comment: I'm not the question starter, sorry

Comment: I know. The comment was directed to the OP.